# If Generic is the key of an object, the type cannot be known

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
type A = {
  key1: string;
  key2: string;
  key3: string;
};

type Key = keyof A;

type NewA = { [P in keyof A]?: string };

function Test(value: keyof A) {
  const obj: NewA = { [value]: "new string" };
}
```

The above code works fine. But using generic it doesn't work.

```
type A<T> = { [P in keyof T]?: string };

class Class<T> {
  func(value: keyof T) {
    const Obj: A<T> = {
      [value]: "asdfasdf",
    };
  }
}
```

I found a workaround, but I don't like it.
Maybe there is something wrong with the code in the second code block?
First of all, one of the solutions is to use as, which is avoided as much as possible.
I was wondering if there are other workarounds.

Comment: This is a design limitation of TypeScript, see [ms/TS#47703](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47703).  There are all kinds of workarounds, but the easiest is just to use a type assertion like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WGVZ2m).  Anything else is probably overkill for such a minimal example (the workaround would be more verbose than the rest of your code).  Does that fully address your question?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?